Jboss EAP 8.0 not able to resolve the endpoints in the spring (and springboot) application after upgrading to 8.0 EAP. Getting 404 - Not Found
I have a spring application which needs to be upgraded to latest framework(6.1.5) and java 17.
To host the upgraded app, I must upgrade my Jboss server to 8.0 from 7.4.
I have made all the changes needed for the upgrade, both application and server.
Now after deploying the war file on to server, I am getting 404 non found error for the end point in one of the deployments.
I have an endpoint with Get and Post methods for the same one. Neither is working.
When I have enabled the debug level logs, I could see
Matched prefix path /<warfilename> for path /<warfilename> /<endpoint>

to endpoint but the server is not able to resolve the endpoint and throwing 404.
I can see the call coming to server in the logs.
For 404 not found below is the response in the logs. This is happening for the endpoint coming from spring application.
--------------------------RESPONSE--------------------------
            contentLength=68
            contentType=text/html;charset=UTF-8
            header=Connection=keep-alive
            header=Content-Type=text/html;charset=UTF-8
            header=Content-Length=68
            header=Date=Fri, 12 Apr 2024 02:30:19 GMT
            status=404

But when I fetch a html page from another war file it works fine, which means the server fetches the page and below is the response in the logs, got 200 success code.
--------------------------RESPONSE--------------------------
            contentLength=40734
            contentType=text/html
            header=X-Powered-By=Undertow/1
            header=Access-Control-Allow-Headers=accept, authorization,  content-type, x-requested-with
            header=Server=WildFly/10
            header=Accept-Ranges=bytes
            header=Date=Tue, 16 Apr 2024 18:13:25 GMT
            header=:status=200
            header=Access-Control-Allow-Origin=*
            header=Last-Modified=Mon, 27 Nov 2023 23:11:46 GMT
            header=Access-Control-Allow-Credentials=true
            header=Content-Type=text/html
            header=Content-Length=40734
            header=Access-Control-Allow-Methods=GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT
            header=Access-Control-Max-Age=1
            status=200

I am focused on hosting Spring 6.1.5 application on JBoss EAP 8.0.
I am expecting there might be some configurations responsible to resolve this but I am able to find proper blogs describing the similar issues. Any help is much appreciated.

Did you by chance also migrate the javax -> jakarta namespace? That would be required. Short of that, I don't see much to go on here. Do you have some logs that can be shared?
